# issue with php SQL queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am new to the whole php sql thing and I am trying to build a form and insert data from its fields to an sql table. My problem is that only the first field inserts the data. Here is code.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user348';
$dbpass = 'anbidVio';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $emp_name = addslashes ($_POST['emp_name']);
   $emp_address = addslashes ($_POST['emp_address']);
}
else
{
   $emp_name = $_POST['emp_name'];
   $emp_address = $_POST['emp_address'];
}
$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO projectdb ".
       "(name, lastname, email, phone, position, hotelname, gender, adress) ".
       "VALUES('$emp_name','$emp_lname','$emp_mail', '$emp_phone', '$emp_job', '$emp_hotel', '$emp_gender', '$emp_adress' )";
mysql_select_db('user348_db2');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Name</td>
<td><input name="emp_name" type="text" id="emp_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Last Name</td>
<td><input name="emp_lname" type="text" id="emp_lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Email</td>
<td><input name="emp_mail" type="text" id="emp_mail"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Phone</td>
<td><input name="emp_phone" type="text" id="emp_phone"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Τύπος Εργασίας</td>
<td>
<select name="tasks" id="emp_job">
<option value="task1" >Tour Operator</option>
<option value="task2" selected="selected">Υπάλληλος</option>
<option value="task3">Διεύθυνση</option></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Ξενοδοχείο</td>
<td><select name="tasks"id="emp_hotel">
<option value="task1" >Village Heights</option>
<option value="task2" selected="selected">Agapi Beach</option>
<option value="task3">Malia Park</option>
<option value="task3">Blue Palace</option>
<option value="task3">Koutouloufari Apartments</option></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Φύλο</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="emp_gender" value="female">Θήλυ
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="emp_gender" value="male">Άρρεν</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Address</td>
<td><input name="emp_address" type="text" id="emp_addres"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Employee">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

All help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: 1) don't use `mysql_*` functions 2) read about SQL-injection

Comment: You only assigned a few variables for POST. Plus, you have no named element for `emp_salary`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which will help you debug your code, which is just that, a debugging issue.

Comment: Plus, possible typos `adress)` for your column name and `id="emp_addres"` if you're using JS/Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Properly get the data for all the input elements and then you insert it iF you had got the values properly then post your code fully

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user348';
$dbpass = 'anbidVio';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('user348_db2');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $emp_name = addslashes ($_POST['emp_name']);
   $emp_address = addslashes ($_POST['emp_address']);
}
else
{
   $emp_name = $_POST['emp_name'];
   $emp_address = $_POST['emp_address'];
}
$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO projectdb (name, lastname, email, phone, position, hotelname, gender, adress) 
       VALUES('".$emp_name."','".$emp_lname."','".$emp_mail."','".$emp_phone."', '".$emp_job."', '".$emp_hotel."', '".$emp_gender."', '".$emp_adress."' )";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Name</td>
<td><input name="emp_name" type="text" id="emp_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Last Name</td>
<td><input name="emp_lname" type="text" id="emp_lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Email</td>
<td><input name="emp_mail" type="text" id="emp_mail"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Phone</td>
<td><input name="emp_phone" type="text" id="emp_phone"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Τύπος Εργασίας</td>
<td>
<select name="tasks" id="emp_job">
<option value="task1" >Tour Operator</option>
<option value="task2" selected="selected">Υπάλληλος</option>
<option value="task3">Διεύθυνση</option></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Ξενοδοχείο</td>
<td><select name="tasks"id="emp_hotel">
<option value="task1" >Village Heights</option>
<option value="task2" selected="selected">Agapi Beach</option>
<option value="task3">Malia Park</option>
<option value="task3">Blue Palace</option>
<option value="task3">Koutouloufari Apartments</option></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Φύλο</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="emp_gender" value="female">Θήλυ
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="emp_gender" value="male">Άρρεν</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Address</td>
<td><input name="emp_address" type="text" id="emp_addres"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Employee">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You have error in action tag in form 
insted of `$_PHP_SELF` use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for redirecting on same page